# RoutingError inside an iFrame

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, routes

**I scaffolded a test app and got a Routing error when I put an iFrame inside my view:**

This is the show template where I added the iFrame:

**views/bars/show.html.erb:**

```
<p>
  <b>Body:</b>
  <%=h @bar.body %>
</p>

<iframe src=“http://www.yahoo.com” style=“width:500px; height:500px;” frameborder=“0?></iframe>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_bar_path(@bar) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', bars_path %>
```

**I'm calling the page like this:**

```
http://localhost:3000/bars/1
```

**The page displays correctly. But the iFrame inside the page says this:**

```
Routing Error

No route matches "/bars/%E2%80%9Chttp://www.yahoo.com%E2%80%9D" 
with {:method=>:get}
```

**I didn't make any changes to routes.rb from the defaults:**

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :bars
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the right double quote character, which is "

Comment: You probably copied it somewhere of the internets

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Yes, I copied some code off a webpage. I don't know why it copied like that.